# Logging into a website using Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python and I'm trying to log into a website using the Requests module and print out some of my account information. See code below :

```
import requests

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
URL = 'https://www.mmoga.com/login.php'
payload = {'email_address': username, 'password': password}

session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
account = session.get('https://www.mmoga.com/shopping_cart.php')
print account.content
```

Do I also have to add headers to the `requests.post`?

When I look at the html source I am seeing

```
<div class="boxHeading">
  <a href="mmoga.com/login.php"; title="- My Account -">- My Account -</a>
</div>
```

however I should be seeing

```
<div class="boxHeading">
  <a href="mmoga.com/account.php"; title="- My Account -">- My Account -</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you let us know what response you get, and how it was different from your expectations?

Comment: Have you read this ... http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.0-0/user/authentication/

Comment: @EricWilson When I look at the html source I am seeing <div class="boxHeading"><a href="https://www.mmoga.com/login.php" title="- My Account -">- My Account -</a></div> however I should be seeing <div class="boxHeading"><a href="https://www.mmoga.com/account.php" title="- My Account -">- My Account -</a></div>

Comment: I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting the the login form on that page you also need to pass a query string with a "get" parameter named `action`:

```
import requests

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
URL = 'https://www.mmoga.com/login.php'
payload = {'email_address': username, 'password': password}
params = {'action': 'process'}

session = requests.session()
r = session.post(URL, data=payload, params=params)
account = session.get('https://www.mmoga.com/shopping_cart.php')
print account.content
```

That should fix the login problem. Also, the session is not being used during login, so you should use `session.post()` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

- Looking at https://www.mmoga.com the login URL seems to be: https://www.mmoga.com/login.php?action=process
- i think you should use the session object for the POST too, so that credential cookies are actually stored in it

  r = session.post(URL, data=payload)